# JMX Client Eclipse issue

Tags: java, jmx

I am trying to create JMX Client application.

I run my JMX application with following command:

```
java -cp . -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1234 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false MyJMXClass
```

Now when I run the client application from terminal, it works fine.

```
java -cp . MyJMXClient
```

But when I run the same program from Eclipse, I got following exception.

```
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1234; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

I am confused why it works fine from terminal but not in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the issue, I had the run configurations saved earlier in the Eclipse for JMX port and thats why it was throwing this exception, once removed it worked fine.